# Copying file with both strings and integer in other file but in reverse order

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm storing scores of game rounds in a file. The file to which I register such scores is like this:

```
James 10
```

The next time James plays, the score restarts from 10, and is stored in, for example, like this:

```
James 10
James 20
```

The third time James plays, the score restarts from 10, and not 20. Is there any possible solution for it? I thought of making a new file in a reverse order. However, I have no idea of how to do so. I want to restart my game with the latest score of an individual. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm pasting here only the part related to the score. If anyone needs more of the code, let me know.

```
cout << "Please enter your name : ";
    getline(cin, name);
    ifstream inFile("Scores.txt", ios::in);
    if(inFile.is_open()) {

        while(!inFile.eof())
        {
            string temp;
            int sc;
            inFile >> temp;
            inFile >> sc;
            if(temp == name) {
                score = sc;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would writing it in reverse order be useful? Surely what you want is to store each player's name and score exactly once.

Comment: Yeah i also tried it but it wasn't working so i thought of reversing it and when again it'll be read from start, the latest score will be read first. Overwriting the score was not working with me.

Comment: void WriteScore(string name) {
 ofstream outFile("Scores.txt", ios::app | ios::out);
 outFile << name << " " << score << endl;
 outFile.flush();
 outFile.close();
}

Comment: i am using this code for writing scores. Oh sorry i am actually new to overflow. I dont know how to make it appear like code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to write it in reverse order.
Just remove `break;` after `score=sc;` and you'll get the latest score of a player.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you change the way you keep track of score? Here is my proposal:

1. Store only a single line per user
2. The line looks like the following `"<username> <initial_score> <best_score>"`
3. When a new user plays the game for the first time store something like this: `"bob 10 10"`

The only caveat here is that you need to be able to edit the record for bob in the text file, typically you would load the file on start into some "database", then as operations occur modify the db in memory (while flushing to your file as you see fit).

**Edit: Lazy Solution:**

The lazier solution would involve reading `bob`'s last score, creating a new entry to the file and blindly adding it to the end. This way when looking for his best score, all you need to do is find the last entry for `bob` by reading from end -> start.

I think the fundamental problem here is you are trying to keep track of two distinct things (initial score, and best score) using a single pattern.